# Is it possible to use custom GUI magnifications?

Tags: front-end, customization, menu

I am running Mathematica 7 on Windows XP Pro. I often use the magnification feature to zoom in on `Plot`s, `ListPlot`s, and `Graphics` that I have created. If I go to the **Window** menu, there is a **Magnification** option, which gives a submenu with the following options:

- 50%
- 100%
- 125%
- 150%
- 200%
- 300%

Is it possible to use a magnification of, for example, 110%?

Comment: Andrew, I am editing your question to make it version-independent.  I don't think this should be a problem as you already received a solution but let me know if it is.

Comment: People may want to know that the default `Magnification` option for `$FrontEnd` is 1 and for `EvaluationNotebook[]` it is `Inherited`. If you zoom using the menu at the bottom, this changes the  `EvaluationNotebook[]`'s `Magnification` option to say `1.25 Inherited`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this might help:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],DockedCells->
Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[DynamicModule[{m=1},Panel[Slider[
Dynamic[m,SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],Magnification->(m=#)]&],{0.5,2.0}],
"Magnification"]]]],"DockedCell"]]
```

It puts a magnification control into a docked cell at the top of the notebook window.

Answer (score 9):

Since you reference the `Window > Magnification` menu I think you are describing zoom for the entire Notebook.

You can set magnification in 10% increments by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and rolling the mouse wheel up or down.

By first setting the Magnification to 125% you get 115%, 135% etc, and you can therefore select magnification down to 5% granularity very quickly.

---

Other magnification values can be set using the Option Inspector or `SetOptions`.  You can for example zoom all Notebooks at once (which do not have Magnification values set internally) with:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, Magnification -> 1.17]
```

Answer (score 7):

You cannot directly do that from the `Window > Zoom` menu option. However, you can use the following to zoom selections at other magnification levels. The following code creates a palette that lets you magnify a selection in your notebook between 50% to 300% in steps of 10.

```
DynamicModule[{zoom = 1},
    CreatePalette[Column@{
    "Custom zoom",
    Dynamic@Row[{
        Button["-", zoom -= 0.1, Enabled -> (zoom >= 0.5)], 
        100 zoom, 
        Button["+", zoom += 0.1, Enabled -> (zoom <= 3)]
    }],
    Dynamic@Button["Zoom selection", 
        SetOptions[NotebookSelection[SelectedNotebook[]], Magnification -> zoom]]
    }]
]
```

---

Evaluating the above code creates a palette like the following:

[image]

Now just select anything in your notebook, use the +/- buttons to increase/decrease the magnification and click the button. Here's an example where I've zoom parts of the above code in my notebook:

[image]

Comment: my eyes! ... :)