# Custom Magnification Setting

Tags: front-end, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Mathematica 7 for Windows, is it possible to use custom GUI magnifications?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8577/in-mathematica-7-for-windows-is-it-possible-to-use-custom-gui-magnifications)

I am able to use a custom Magnification by setting `Magnification->1.05` in my Notebook options. The FrontEnd only displays 1.0 1.25 1.5 etc. So if I switch once, I cannot go back without editing the file by hand.

Is there a way to modify the Magnification menu such as to include other (finer) values like 1.05, 1.10, 1.16, 1.33 ?

Comment: I was thinking of modifying the menu like in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/how-make-addmenucommands-work-in-an-init-m this is not covered in the "duplicate"

Comment: That answer covers different possible ways to control custom magnification. You can combine the techniques there with [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/907/5) to add to a menu.

Comment: @rm-rf have you actually tried that?  Does modifying the **Window > Magnification** menu also change the lower-right popup menu?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, I tried it before commenting and Andy's answer works very well (I'm on a Mac). As for the latter question, when you change via the menu, it shows the current magnification in the lower-right popup, but it does not add the new value to it (it probably reads from the default and needs to be changed separately). In fact, I didn't even know that there was a popup there until you mentioned it.