# Changing Default Notebook Window Magnification level

Tags: notebooks, display

I have searched for an answer to this problem in Mathematica documentation, googling, and here on this Mathematica.SE forum.  So far, no answer that I can find.

When a new Notebook window is opened, the default magnification level is 100 %.  It is changeable (I use the selection box at the bottom of the window) to values less and greater percentages.  I prefer 125%.

I would like to change the default so that I do not have to continuously make these changes when a new Notebook is opened.  I want this default to live across startup/shutdown of Mathematica and my computer (Mac).  None of the other techniques I have found allow me to make such a default value change.

I am presuming that there is an init.m or config.m file somewhere in my installation that allows me to make this change.  Does anyone know of a method to do this?

My platform is Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite).  I am running Mathematica 10.0.1.

Comment: This answer might be useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8591/131

Comment: Well, that does not answer my question from what I can tell.  I know how to change the magnification for the current session, current window, and so on which is what your link seems to described.  But, this does not apply (as far as I know) to changes that are permanent and live across the startup/shutdown of Mathematica or Computer.

Comment: Ah,  that was the one I was looking for (possible dupe): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1310/131

Comment: @YvesKlett -- Thanks for the link.  That did the trick but I saw this dupe before and tried it and it did not work.  Or, I didn't think it worked is the more accurate statement.  I was testing the result by looking for the magnification value to change from 100 to 125 percent down at the bottom of the window.  But, this does not change.  What happens is that the notion of 100 % as indicated in the window is now referring to the base level of 125 % set by the SetOptions command.  Not exactly working the way I would have liked  but it does work.