# How to put Magnification control in docked cell

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, docked-cell

I have made a handy toolbar that provides access to menu items that are not visible when I <kbd>F12</kbd> a workbook.

[image]
I would like to add the following function to a button in the toolbar:

```
magnification = 1.0;
SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
Magnification :> Dynamic[magnification] ];
Slider[Dynamic[magnification], {0.8, 2, .01}]
```

which gives me a `Slider` with more control over the notebooks magnification.
[image]

However, although I can put the `Slider` in a `Button`, when I add the `Button` to the row of docked cells, it won't do anything.  Can this be made to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basing only on your description I can't really diagnose the problem. Let me put here something what does what you need but with a slightly different approach:

You don't have to set Magnification to be dynamic and dependent of any symbols, let the `Slider` itself to change the `Magnification`:

```
SetOptions[
 EvaluationNotebook[],
 DockedCells -> {
   ToBoxes @ DynamicModule[{x}, 
     Slider[Dynamic[ x, 
         (x = CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification] = #) &
         ], {.8, 2, .01}]
     ]
   }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice!  I'll use this.  It's not at all what I would have done, so I'll use it to figure out what I didn't know.

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe Feel free to ask if anything is not clear.

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8585/862)

Comment: @SimonWoods at least closely :)

Comment: @f_s and which notebook's magnification do you want to control?