# How to set dynamically stylesheet definitions?

Tags: dynamic, notebooks, stylesheet

To produce good color schemes for styling notebook I was used to generate a grid of controls

```
grid = {
   {Dynamic[background], 
    ColorSlider[Dynamic[background], ImageSize -> {800, 100}, 
     AppearanceElements -> "Spectrum"]},
   {Dynamic[fontColor], 
    ColorSlider[Dynamic[fontColor], ImageSize -> {800, 100}, 
     AppearanceElements -> "Spectrum"]},
   {Dynamic[cellframecolor], 
    ColorSlider[Dynamic[cellframecolor], ImageSize -> {800, 100}, 
     AppearanceElements -> "Spectrum"]}
   };
Grid @ grid
```

and print a cell whose options are manipulated through the previous sliders:

```
CellPrint[Cell["this", "Text"
   , CellFrame -> True
   , CellFrameColor -> Dynamic[cellframecolor]
   , Background -> Dynamic[background]
   , FontColor -> Dynamic[fontColor]
   ]
  ];
```

How can the same be achieved for the whole notebook's stylesheet, not for the specific cell ? I have not been capable to get it using `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], "StyleDefinitions"]`.

Comment: Whatever you want to do, put them in stylesheet or just `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],...]` keep in mind that `cellframecolor` will not survive through sessions and next time you open the notebook it will be broken.

Comment: In [How to put Magnification control in docked cell](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/107816/5478) I have explained how to continuously change notebook's `Magnification`, you can do the same with other options.

Comment: Hi! That `cellframecolor` get lost between sessions isn't an issue for the use I make of it: I can save as you explained yesterday in 
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108266/an-issue-regarding-the-use-of-copytoclipboard-with-dynamic-content. My block is about `CurrentValue`: I have been experimenting with no result: please, can you provide a simple example to set, let's say, the background color for Title cells style ?

Comment: Options for a notebook are ok, provided that I can save their values, to put them in a stylesheet by hand.

Comment: Is this useful? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/defining-functions-in-stylesheets/7744#7744

Comment: Yes ! This do the job: `ColorSlider[Dynamic[fontColor], ImageSize -> {800, 100}, 
 AppearanceElements -> "Spectrum"]
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions -> 
  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["Text"], FontColor -> Dynamic[fontColor]]}, 
   StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you are looking for?

[image]

If so possible [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/defining-functions-in-stylesheets/7744#7744).

Comment: Excellent reference: I'm going to read it in in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ? :

```
grid = {
   {Dynamic[background], 
    ColorSlider[Dynamic[background], ImageSize -> {800, 100}, 
     AppearanceElements -> "Spectrum"]},
   {Dynamic[fontColor], 
    ColorSlider[Dynamic[fontColor], ImageSize -> {800, 100}, 
     AppearanceElements -> "Spectrum"]},
   {Dynamic[cellframecolor], 
    ColorSlider[Dynamic[cellframecolor], ImageSize -> {800, 100}, 
     AppearanceElements -> "Spectrum"]}
   };

Grid @ grid

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["Text"], {
      CellFrame -> True,
      CellFrameColor -> Dynamic[cellframecolor],
      Background -> Dynamic[background],
      FontColor -> Dynamic[fontColor]}]}]]

 CellPrint[Cell["this", "Text"]]
 CellPrint[Cell["that", "Text"]]
```

Comment: Fits perfectly my needs. Thanks !